# When click event, the element is added and disappears immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Question</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" id="more-item" placeholder="addSomething" required autocomplete="off">
        <button id="more">add</button>
    </form>
    <ul id="items">
        <li class="item">work</li>
        <li class="item">relax</li>
        <li class="item">game</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

```
$('#more').on('click', function() {
const item = $('#more-item').val();
  if (item !== '') {
    $('#items').append('<li class="item">' + String(item) + '</li>');
  } 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mj70Lzey/

When I add the li tag, it is added and immediately disappears from the screen, resulting in a 404 error. What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You're submitting your form and the page reloads. The default type of a button element is submit. Just change it to button:

```
<button id="more" type="button">add</button>
```

```js
$('#more').on('click', function() {
  const item = $('#more-item').val();
  if (item !== '') {
    $('#items').append('<li class="item">' + String(item) + '</li>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <input type="text" id="more-item" placeholder="addSomething" required autocomplete="off">
  <button type="button" id="more">add</button>
</form>

<ul id="items">
  <li class="item">work</li>
  <li class="item">relax</li>
  <li class="item">game</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add prevent default. The button is submitting the form and reloading the page.

https://jsfiddle.net/35oabq20/

```
$('#more').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

const item = $('#more-item').val();
  if (item !== '') {
    $('#items').append('<li class="item">' + String(item) + '</li>');
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because default type button is `submit`, when you click button in form, your `action=""` so it will reload page.

Change button type to button will fix your issue `<button id="more" type="button">add</button>`

JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/08eq1pwv/1/

```js
$('#more').on('click', function() {
const item = $('#more-item').val();
  if (item !== '') {
    $('#items').append('<li class="item">' + String(item) + '</li>');
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Question</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"> 
</head>
<body>
 <form action="">
  <input type="text" id="more-item" placeholder="addSomething" required autocomplete="off">
  <button id="more" type="button">add</button>
 </form>

 <ul id="items">
  <li class="item">work</li>
  <li class="item">relax</li>
  <li class="item">game</li>
 </ul>

</body>
</html>
```